# What are the clues on how 'vivid' someone's sensory imagination is?

Tags: perception

For example, I can imagine me eating barbecue with some details, like appearance,  smell, temperature, taste etc, and I end up experiencing all these qualities to a certain extent. But I guess each one of us feels it with a different intensity. Is there a way to verify that? Are different levels of sensory imagination associated with some personality traits?

I think this is a related question, but it does not talk about the intensity of it: [What happens when a person "imagines" how food could taste like just from looking at it?](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/1634/what-happens-when-a-person-imagines-how-food-could-taste-like-just-from-lookin)